# GNU make: Generate rules for extracting tarballs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a Makefile that extracts a series of tarballs.  Right now the rules are written like:

```
dirname:
        tar zxvf file.tar.gz
```

and other targets that depend on the expanded tarball reference `dirname`.  But, it's kind of cluttery to define a rule like this for every tarball.  So, I'm trying to use the `eval` function to auto generate these rules.  My attempt looks like this:

```
TARFILES = $(wildcard *.tar.gz *.tgz)
define extract_tmpl =
 $(shell tar tf $(1) | head -1):
        tar zxvf $(1)
endef
$(foreach file, $(TARFILES), $(eval $(call extract_tmpl, $(file))))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm testing with this tarball (in the same dir):

```
$ ls Python-2.6.6.tgz 
Python-2.6.6.tgz
$ tar tf Python-2.6.6.tgz | head -1
Python-2.6.6/
$ make Python-2.6.6/
make-3.79.1-p7: *** No rule to make target `Python-2.6.6/'.  Stop.
```

It seems like it should work to me, but honestly I'm not even sure how I can see what it expands to.  Anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You do not need an `=` after the `define`.
- There should be a hard tab before the `tar zxvf $(1)`
- Optional, define a rule called `default` as the first rule in the Makefile, which depends on all the directories that would be created, so that if you just run `make`, it would extract all the tarballs.
- Optional, but good practice is to define `default` as a `PHONY` rule since it does not create any files called `default`.

This is how the `Makefile` would look like (and tested using 2 tarballs in the current directory):

```
TARFILES = $(wildcard *.tar.gz *.tgz)

define extract_tmpl
$(shell tar tf $(1) | head -1):
    tar zxvf $(1)
# ^
# HARD-TAB
#
endef

TAR_DIRS := $(foreach file, $(TARFILES), $(shell tar tf $(file) | head -1))

default: $(TAR_DIRS)

$(foreach file, $(TARFILES), $(eval $(call extract_tmpl, $(file))))

.PHONY: default
```

An alternate solution without using `eval` and just [`static pattern rules`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html):

- Used `.extract_file.tar.gz` or `.extract_file.tgz` as empty files to not re-extract the archives if already extracted
- No eval, but just static pattern rules, which should make it compatible with older versions of make like v3.79
- Added rules for clean

This is the `Makefile`:

```
TARFILES = $(wildcard *.tar.gz *.tgz)

EXTRACT_TARGETS := $(addprefix .extract_,$(TARFILES))
CLEAN_TARGETS := $(addprefix .clean_,$(TARFILES))

default: $(EXTRACT_TARGETS)

clean: $(CLEAN_TARGETS)

$(CLEAN_TARGETS): .clean_%: .extract_%
    rm -rf "$(shell tar tf $(patsubst .extract_%,%,$<) | head -1)"
    rm -f $<

$(EXTRACT_TARGETS): .extract_%: %
    tar zxf $<
    touch $@

.PHONY: default clean $(CLEAN_TARGETS)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Also, it seems make 3.79 does not have `eval` which was part of my problem.

Comment: @FatalError - Have added an alternate solution just making use of `static pattern rules` and no `eval` if you need to use an older version of `make`. :)